# Connecting to local instance of PostgreSql with JDBC for tuffy

Tags: java, postgresql, ubuntu

I can login into Postgres using "`psql -h localhost -U myuser mydatabase`"

But my tuffy config file is like this :

```
# JDBC connection string; must be PostgreSQL
db_url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb

# Database username; must be a superuser
db_username = myuser

# The password for db_username
db_password = mypass

# The working directory; Tuffy may write sizable temporary data here
dir_working = /var/postgres/data
```

But when I run tuffy commands, it show error like this :

> Connecting to RDBMS at jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tuffydb Failed
>   to connect to PostgreSQL! FATAL: password authentication failed for
>   user "tuffer" Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at tuffy.db.RDB.query(RDB.java:438) at
>   tuffy.db.RDB.schemaExists(RDB.java:676) at
>   tuffy.db.RDB.resetSchema(RDB.java:717) at
>   tuffy.main.Infer.setUp(Infer.java:77) at
>   tuffy.main.PartInfer.run(PartInfer.java:18) at
>   tuffy.main.Main.main(Main.java:29)